# OO PHP and MVC: calling a method from another controller?

Tags: php, class, oop, model-view-controller, controller

This may be due to a gap in my understanding of the PHP Object-Oriented model, but bear with me and see if you find it makes any sense/any glaring errors. Anyways, in a MVC app I have two controllers, `Post.php` and `Thread.php`. In the `Thread` controller I have a `public` method `mark_as_read()` which does as you could guess. It marks a thread as read (insert row in DB) or updates the time of the last view in the database. In the `Thread` controller I can call it easily by doing:

```
$this->mark_as_read($user_id, $thread_id);
```

However, in the `Post` controller I also want to be able to mark a thread as read, specifically when I make a new post and I don't want the database to reflect that the user hasn't read their own "new" post. **First question:** how can I call the `mark_as_read()` method on a thread from the post controller?

Anyways, I tinkered around and solved this problem in a way which seems **very** bad to me by instinct. There is a `Base` controller that both the `Post` and `Thread` controllers inherit from. I moved the `mark_as_read()` method into the base controller, and now I can mark a thread as read by calling the same:

```
$this->mark_as_read($user_id, $thread_id);
```

From ANY controller! The reason this seems really bad to me is because I have other controllers where I'm not sure I really want to mark threads as read, and instinctively it doesn't feel like it belongs there. I am pretty sure I'm doing this wrong... so **question two:** how do I do it the "right" way? I'm using Laravel 3 (http://laravel.com/) but this seems like a general OO PHP question, not specific to the framework.

Comment: If I can answer any clarifying questions feel free to ask...

Comment: I also thought I could make the method static... but then wouldn't that solution be even uglier?

Comment: mark_as_read should be a model action on the thread, not on the controller

Comment: @Orangepill trying that now.. makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question I would ask is : what class should *mark_as_read(*) belong to ?

The MVC pattern allows you to separate layers : the controller is in charge of organizing the job, it delegates most of the real actions to the *view* (*display* stuff) and to the *model* (any *db or data-structure* related stuff).

That's why, IMHO, *mark_as_read()* should be a method of the *Thread* **model** class. The controller should only call `$myThread->mark_as_read()` within its actions.

Thus,

1. any controller can easily mark a thread as read, as long as he has a *Thread* **model** instance available.
2. any post can easily mark its thread as read, since I guess a *Post* model object has some pointer to its parent thread (emulating the foreign key relationship in the post table of the database)

Comment: Okay so I'm adding it to the model... then how should I call it? Assuming $thread is the appropriate thread object. `$thread->mark_as_read($user_id, $thread_id);`?

Comment: should be able to omit the thread_id unless the instance has an identity crisis

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. As I wrote it, it takes 2 params `$user_id` and `$thread_id` but if I have it in the thread model, I can just pass the user id and set the thread id to `$this->id`?

Comment: Also if posts and threads dont share an ancestor or child relationship but they do share the same mark_as_read behavior it might be worth creating a separate ReadMarker class to abstract the behavior

Comment: Good call. In this case, only threads can be "marked as read" but I can think of extending the app and wanting to do that now...